# Multiple selectable GridView

Tags: android

OK, so I think I've exhausted searching for this question, and it's either that I'm totally missing something or nobody else has tried to create a GridView (showing images) which allows the user to select multiple images.  Basically I want to have the orange selection box appear whenever a user selects an image, or disappear if the user has already chosen the image.

Is this something that I'll have to roll myself with a customer View?  I may also try including a CheckBox with each image and have the CheckBox selected if the image is.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

- michael

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/ThisdemoillustratestheuseofCHOICEMODEMULTIPLEMODALakaselectionmodeonGridView.htm) -- they use a custom layout class that implements Checkable interface and set a colored background-drawable on checked items.

Answer (score 1):

Just draw a checkbox onto the cell's bitmap when selected. Draw the original when toggle unchecked.

```
  private Bitmap drawCheck(Bitmap bmp)
  {
   Bitmap bmChecked = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),     bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
   Bitmap check = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.upcheck);
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmChecked);

   canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
   canvas.drawBitmap(check, 0, 0, null); 
   return bmChecked;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used an excellent [code by Mihai Fonoage](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html).

And then:

1. added a selected flag to LoadedImage class,
2. in the onItemClick() function I mark the clicked item as selected
3. in the adapter's getView() use the flag to i.e. set the image background

IT WORKS.

Comment: Well I am not sure I can post his code. If you thoroughly analyze the code from the link, and then do what I pointed out, I am sure you won't go a wrong way.