# Batch Selection of bitmaps/ImageViews android

Tags: android, select, batch-file, imageview, batch-processing

Suppose I have a grid of images, How do you select imageviews or bitmaps in batch mode? And how do you do a 'select all'?

Comment: what have you tried so far ???,, made custom gridView layout and set images to it with checkbox ????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191379/multiple-selectable-gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding ImageViews in your GridView, add Custom Layouts consisting of an ImageView and a Checkbox.

You can add a OnCheckedChangeListener to the Checkbox, so that whenever an image selected/deselected, you can add/remove the id of that image to an ArrayList.

Alternatively, when you select a button to perform an operation on selected items, you can iterate through the GridView and check if the checkbox is checked or not.

If you want to implement a "Select All" functionality, iterate through the GridView and set the CheckBox states to selected.

Comment: Thank you. How can I do it without using checkboxes? For eg, in QuickPic, a red border appears around the thumbnail that is selected. How can that be implemented? Is it onClickListener for each thumbnail? Is this a custom layout too?

Comment: Depends. If you want to implement selection on click of the imageview, you won't be able to open the image in full screen on click. You can assign selection to tap and hold in that case. You can use imageview.setBackgroundDrawable() and give an image that is slightly larger than your thumbnail to show a selection..

Comment: Actually, when I am in batch mode, I wouldn't have to open the image, clicking would mean selection. So, I could just have different onclick listeners in batch mode and normal mode.

Comment: That is a part of implementation and dependent on what method you're comfortable with.. :-)